# How to make a Google Sheet custom function as an Add-On

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

I'm tying to create a custom function for google sheets that will be accessible with an Add-On to Google Sheets.

The problem is when I run the Add-On as a test, when I type in my custom formula it gives me this error: #NAME? Error
Unknown function: 'myfunction'.

For simplicity sake, I have just been using the following simple function so I know the issue isn't with my functions code

```
function myFunction(input) {
  var output = input * 2;
  return output;
}
```

Comment: That exact code works for me. Only things I did was cut/paste/save and then =myFunction(2) = 4.

Comment: Did it work when you ran it as a Test Add-On? Because the function works fine when it is just in the script file for the sheet, but I can't figure out how to make it work when I test it as an Add-On.

Comment: @c.dimock did you find out the answer?

Answer (score 4):

I also tried to write custom function and publish as Add-on, but get "Error Unknown function" in the Spreadsheet.

Wasted several days on it, and finally got it working.

1. You must have a add-on menu.

   Ref: [Custom Functions with add-ons?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30878247/custom-functions-with-add-ons/34381535)
2. You must define the scopes in your manifest.  And the scopes must be the same as your project.

Ref: https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/36763437#comment22

e.g. add this to your appsscript.json file:

```
  "oauthScopes": [
    "https://www.googleapis.com/auth/spreadsheets"
  ],
```

Answer (score 2):

After scouring the web and questions/answers on Stack Overflow, I believe that as of May 2017 this is an Open Bug with GAS Add-ons. I'm curious if you have come to the same conclusion.

I tried Google's own [date_add_and_substract](https://github.com/google/google-apps-script-samples/blob/master/date_add_and_subtract/Code.gs) Add-on example and couldn't get it to work myself. It's supposed to illustrate the difference between the **Installed for Current User** and **Enabled in Current Document** Add-on states. When the **Enabled**, the Add-on is supposed to load the following Customer Functions for working with Dates:

- `DATEADD()`
- `DATESUBTRACT()`
- `DATETEST()`

When I run the standalone script as **Test as Add-on**, enabled it, then enter any of those Custom Function into the cell I get that same `#NAME?` `Unknown function: 'XXXXXXX'` Error.

[image: Sample Function BUG in GAS Add-Ons]

In fact this seems to be one of the [Open Bug Tickets](https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/36763437).