# Google sheets add-on custom functions not recognised/working

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets, add-on, custom-function

**Situation**: I have created a new project in Google Apps Script suite. In my Code.gs I have defined two custom functions like so:

[image: Custom function definitions]

**Problem**: When I try to follow the procedure to test the add-on ([instructions here](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/add-ons/test)), with latest code and configuration "*Installed and enabled*", I cant seem to use the custom function defined in my script:

[image: Custom function error]

Any ideas why?

**Additional info**:

If I create a script without going through the G Suite, just by opening Tools>Scripts etc.. the custom functions work. That said, I do need to go the G suite way because Im planning to publish this script as an add-on.

Also, I know the script is working/executing because I have some code that creates a custom menu entry which does appear in the sheet.

Comment: It appears that custom functions must be bound to a sheet... https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/sheets/functions#sharing But I'm not able to successfully "Test as add-on" either but that doesn't necessarily mean that it wouldn't work once published?? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30878247/custom-functions-with-add-ons

Comment: @Rubén Youre right its very, very similar question. Which was asked in 2015 tho :/ No way same issue persists. All the links that should help in that post dont exist anymore

Comment: @NeilVarnas There are some issues older than this that are still open. Regarding the links, the last two are about Google Apps Script issues. They point to URLs that are redirected to the current posts on the new issue tracker and both issues are still open.