# Add custom functions to Sheets from Workspace addon

Tags: google-workspace-add-ons

I have a Google Sheets add-on that provides some custom functions along with other functionality exposed in the sidebar. This is working fine. I also have some other miscellaneous scripts for Docs, Slides, etc. I would like to combine all of these into a single Google Workspace add-on so that people in my company only need to install one single add-on instead of multiple.

From what I've read I can understand how to migrate all of my existing functionality into a Workspace add-on **except** the Sheets custom functions. I have not been able to find documentation that definitively says if that is possible or not.

So, my question is, is it possible to make custom functions available to Google Sheets from a Google Workspace add-on? If not, what is the best way to request this to Google?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Custom Functions with add-ons?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30878247/custom-functions-with-add-ons)

Comment: Thanks for the response, but no, that is different. Unfortunately Google's terminology is confusing and imprecise. I already have a Google Sheets add-on (plugin) working, but what I want to do is combine it's functionality with some other functionality into a single Google Workspace add-on. The existing Sheets add-on is an editor add-on specific to Sheets. The Workspace add-on is shown in all Google suite apps, with different functionality exposed depending on the app. See [Add-on types](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/add-ons/concepts/types).