# Enable and disable custom google sheet functions using google apps script

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets, google-sheets-formula, add-on, custom-function

I've been trying to create a Google Spreadsheet plugin from some existing Google App Scripts that I have, and one important part of this app script is Custom Functions.

I have seen an addon that can enable the use of custom sheet functions using a Add-on menu

https://prnt.sc/tlnplvxCwLRQ

Any insights are greatly appreciated.

Comment: I ran some test and I notice that the Add On does not disable the functions, it only enables it. I am unable to find any reference from AppScript to disable the functions, this might be just a trigger, if you do the tutorial or select "Clear API Key" it would activate the "=GTP" function.  Without pressing the button to enable it.

Comment: Questions on this site should be self contained. Considering this, add the image to the question using the button to add images from the question editor toolbar instead of usind a link to an independent host. Please add a [mcve] and add a brief description of your search efforts as is suggested in [ask].

Comment: There's no need to be rude. The question could use some improvement. The first comment above already answers the question.

Answer (score -1):

An add-on's custom functions will work for *all* users of a spreadsheet where the add-on has been *enabled* by *any* user. See [Installed versus enabled](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/add-ons/concepts/editor-auth-lifecycle#installed_versus_enabled).

To enable an add-on in a spreadsheet, run any function in the add-on. The function does not actually need to do anything. Executing any bit of code in the add-on will cause the authorization dialog box to show, and when you give the authorization, the add-on's status changes to enabled for that spreadsheet, and custom functions in the add-on will run in that spreadsheet for all users. Running a function is usually done through a [custom menu item](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/menus).

To disable an add-on, use the **Extensions > Add-ons > Manage add-ons** dialog box.